# How can I make a dynamic treeview in c#?

Tags: c#, xml, dynamic, treeview

I'm working on a system and I've got a treeview which must contain the project structure
from objects.
This structure looks something like this:

```
Project
 |- Module1
 |    |- Xml1
 |    |    |- Element
 |    |    |- Element
 |    |    |    |- Element
 |    |    |    |- Element
 |    |    |    |    |- Element
 |    |    |    |
 |    |    |    |- Element
 |    |    |
 |    |    |- Element
 |    |
 |    |- Xml2
 |         |- Element
 |
 |- Module2
      |- Xml1
           |- Element
```

etc..

Now when i want to add an Xml file to a module it's easy because i know it has
2 nodes above it. (project, module)
in c# :

```
public void AddXmlToTree(string xmlFile)
{
     projectTreeView.Nodes[0].LastNode.Nodes.Add(xmlFile);
}
```

note: i'm using LastNode because i add them in order of the tree.

Now the problem:
Every element can have another element so it is basically limitless.
I can't just make a million methods like that.
I need something else for this maybe some recursive method.

I think I need to get the Node of the last added Element object so 
I can add the next element node to this I just don't know how to get it.

I hope you can understand my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not tested at all, but can be used as direction :

```
private void AddNodesRecursive(TreeNode parent, object childData)
{
    string strChildNode = string.Empty;
    XmlElement childDoc = null;
    if (parent != null)
    {
        if ((childData as string) != null)
        {
            parent.ChildNodes.Add(new TreeNode((childData as string)));
            return;
        }
        childDoc = childData as XmlElement;
        if (childDoc != null)
        {
            TreeNode subParent = new TreeNode(childDoc.InnerText);
            parent.ChildNodes.Add(subParent);
            foreach (XmlElement grandChild in childDoc.ChildNodes)
                AddNodesRecursive(subParent, grandChild);
        }
    }
}
```